# Clearing console before build in Webpack

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

I'm using webpack 3 and I'd like to know is there any way to clear webpack-dev-server console before webpack rebuild.

Comment: `webpack-dev-server` does not have a console. What are you referring to?

Comment: If you are referring to terminal in OSX: hit CMD-K before you make changes to your code :)

Comment: @brandNew it doesn't have a console, it outputs to console. So it could do something like executing `clear` before built.

Comment: *I think* he's referring to clearing the browser console each time HMR replaces a module. For example: you have a syntax error that shows up in the console, as you're trying to fix it, it's faster to know that it's fixed if the console is cleared on each change.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This can be done using the [`clean-terminal-webpack-plugin`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/clean-terminal-webpack-plugin) npm module.

Using this webpack plugin is supprisenly easy, as there is no configuration required for this module, you just have to add the plugin to the list of plugins in webpack.

Instructions from the readme of the npm module:

> **Usage**
>
> Via webpack config file:
>
> ```
> // webpack.config.js
>
> const CleanTerminalPlugin = require('clean-terminal-webpack-plugin');
>
> module.exports = {
>   plugins: [new CleanTerminalPlugin()]
> };
> ```

Comment: Works great, but could this be possible with Visual Studio task runner ?